# PHP Openldap retrive all attributes asked but "location"

Tags: php, attributes, openldap

I'm making a sort of phone book and everything is fine:

- Connection and authentification works perfectly
- Research goes aswell
- I can modify user's attributes

Then my boss asked me to add the Location attribute aka "Bureau" in french but openldap won't retrive it and only it.

Here's the code :

```
$attributes = array();
$attributes[] = 'givenname';
$attributes[] = 'sn';
$attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
$attributes[] = 'mail';
$attributes[] = 'telephonenumber';
$attributes[] = 'useraccountcontrol';
$attributes[] = 'dn';
$attributes[] = 'location';

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
if ($ldap_bind) // Si la connexon s'est effectuée
{
    // Query sur LDAP
    $resultat = ldap_search($ldap_connect, $dn, $search_filter, $attributes) or die('Une erreur est survenue pendant la recherche.');

    // Transformation de l'objet LDAP en données explotables
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connect, $resultat);
```

But when I **var_dump($entries)**, the location attribute isn't in the array, like if the name attribute was wrong. But according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx) it's the right attribute correctly spelled.

So now I turn myself to you in hope someone can help on this issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed using some other method that the entry with DN `$dn` *has* a `location` attribute? Also, make sure the credentials you are using to make the query have access to the `location` attribute.

Comment: It retrive all attributes from 'givenname' to 'dn' (so if it can get 'usersaccountcontrol' it should retrive 'location' too.) The account used to do the connection have administrator rights so it shoud be ok. And yes the entrie which i'm testing this on have the location attribute filled with 'Helpdesk'.

Comment: You say the account you use has "administrator rights". OpenLDAP uses flexible ACLs to control access: can you dump the ACLs and provide the relevant ACL line for the account making the accesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LDAP, if the attribute is not set, it will not be retrieved empty but will not be set in the response entry array.

Retrieve every attribute of the entry and var_dump it to see if it is set.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to mark this question as answered. I took the wrong attribute (it was "office", which I had already tested before but then it worked.)